# Reading and storing nested data

Tags: c++, object-oriented, json, vectors

I'm reading data from a json-structure that describe aquariums and how many fish they contain (among other things). Overall, the structure of the data is like this:

1. "house"

   2. "info"

      3. "animals"

         4. "fish"

As I am looking at aquariums, I only want to keep the data/aquariums that actually contain fish. Here is an example of the data, showing how some aquariums contain fish and others are simply **null**:

```
{
   "country":"UK",
   "house":[
      {
         "type":"aquarium",
         "info":[
            {
               "visitors":10000,
               "animals":[
                  {
                     "address":6,
                     "total":0,
                     "fish":[

                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "visitors":10000,
               "animals":[
                  {
                     "address":7,
                     "total":5,
                     "fish":[
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "address":8,
                     "total":500,
                     "fish":[
                        {
                           "sharks":100,
                           "goldfish":100
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "address":9,
                     "total":23,
                     "fish":[
                        {
                           "sharks":10,
                           "goldfish":20
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I wrote the following program to read the data. Basically, it is structured such that

1. It reads the data file by looping each of the 4 levels above. Whenever an aquarium is found that has a positive, nonzero number of fish, then this data is pushed to a vector that contains all info from the 4 levels.

Currently, each unique combination of (house, info, animals, fish) is kept when **fish** is not null. I think this can be optimized so we keep a nested structure **house->info->animals->fish**, i.e., a vector of **houses** that contains a vector of **info** which contains a vector of **animals** and finally a vector of **fish**.

What is the most professional way to do this? Or do you suggest a different strategy for reading the data?

---

### Code using nlohmann JSON reader## ([link to nlohmann json.hpp](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/tree/develop/src))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"

///////////////////////
///define classes
class Fish
{
  public:
    int sharks;
    int goldfish;
};

class Animals
{
  public:
    std::string address;
    int total;
};

class Info
{
  public:
    int visitors;
};

class House
{
  public:
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m_Info;
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m_Animal;
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m_Fish;

    std::string type;
};
///////////////////////

int main()
{
    ///initialize vector that will contain the desired info
    std::vector<House> house;

    ///load file "fish.json"
    std::ifstream strm("fish.json");
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(strm);

    ///loop over houses (first level of data)
    size_t it_h = 0;
    while (!j["house"][it_h].is_null())
    {

        ///loop over info (second level of data)
        size_t it_f = 0;
        while (!j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f].is_null())
        {

            ///loop over animals (third level of data)
            size_t it_a = 0;
            while (!j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["animals"][it_a].is_null())
            {

                ///loop over fish (fourth level of data)
                size_t it_ff = 0;
                while (!j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["animals"][it_a]["fish"][it_ff].is_null())
                {
                    ///increase "house"-size by 1 in order to add new info
                    house.resize(house.size() + 1);

                    ///add info to "house" at all 4 levels
                    house[it_h].m_Info["visitors"] = j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["visitors"];

                    house[it_h].m_Animal["address"] = j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["animals"][it_a]["address"];
                    house[it_h].m_Animal["total"] = j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["animals"][it_a]["total"];

                    house[it_h].m_Fish["sharks"] = j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["animals"][it_a]["fish"][it_ff]["sharks"];
                    house[it_h].m_Fish["goldfish"] = j["house"][it_h]["info"][it_f]["animals"][it_a]["fish"][it_ff]["goldfish"];

                    it_ff++;
                }
                it_a++;
            }
            it_f++;
        }
        it_h++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very hard to read. I suggest splitting the whole operation up into multiple small functions to increase readability.

Comment: @BenSteffan Thanks, I added comments to the code. It's basically just 4 while-loops that loop over the json-file in the main-function, I'm not sure how to split it up in order to increase readability.

Comment: My idea would be splitting up reading each level into a separate function, i.e. for each house read call a function read_animals, then, for each animal, call a function read_fish etc. either return some data or directly write into your vector.